# Prove that $a:=\inf \{x\in \mathbb Q: x^2\le 2\}$ satisfies $a^2 = 2$

Tags: real-analysis

> Define $S := \{x ∈ \mathbb Q : x^2 ≤ 2\}$. Prove that $a:=\inf \{S\}$
>   satisfies $a^2 = 2$.

Since a is a lower bound for S, we have $a^2\le 2$. if $a^2\neq 2$ then $a^2 < 2$ and we may set $\epsilon:= a^2 − 2 > 0$ and then I am not sure how to show it satisfies $a^2 = 2$.

Comment: no the question says inf{s}

Comment: Either inf or sup would be correct.  The "inf" of the set, as given, is the irrational number $-\sqrt{2}$.  The "sup" is $\sqrt{2}$ and both "inf" and "sup" satisfy $a^2= 2$.

Comment: @user247327 No, it has infimum $a=-\sqrt{2}$, which does in fact satisfy $a^2=2$.

Comment: yes, I see but how do we prove this fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $a=-\sqrt{2}$ and show that $a=\inf\{S\}$. This is equivalent to showing that

- for every $x\in S$, it holds that $x\ge -\sqrt{2}$.
- for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $x\in S$ such that $x<-\sqrt{2}+\epsilon$.

The first one should be straightforward, for the second take $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary and consider $x=-\sqrt{2}+\epsilon/2$.

Just note that $-\sqrt{2}\notin S$ since $-\sqrt{2}\notin \mathbb Q$, so $-\sqrt{2}$ is indeed an $\inf$ but not a $\min$ of set $S$.

Comment: What is this number "$\sqrt{2}$" you are talking about? Does it even exist?

Comment: just 2 things i want to know how you got ϵ/2.... do you have to write out the terms of S and then determine it and i dont fully understand the last sentence could u be a bit more clear

Answer (score 2):

HINT.- $x^2\le2\iff-\sqrt2\le x\le \sqrt2$ and $(-\sqrt2)^2=(\sqrt2)^2=2.$

Comment: can we determine the infS and then take the square to show it satisfies it

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to flesh out the reasoning in your question to solve a more general question.  Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and consider the set
$$
S_f = \{x\in\mathbb{Q} \,:\, f(x) \leq 0\}.
$$
If $S_f$ is nonempty and $S_f\not=\mathbb{R}$, then $x^* = \inf S_f$ satisfies $f(x^*) = 0$.  To apply this to your question, simply set $f(x) = x^2-2$.

To prove it, let $y^* = f(x^*)$.  Suppose $y^*>0$, and let $\epsilon=y^*/2$.  Because $f$ is continuous we can find $\delta$ such that for every $x\in[x^*, x^*+\delta]$, 
$$|f(x)-f(x^*)|<\epsilon.$$
In particular, $f(x) > y^*/2 > 0$.  In particular, $[x^*,x^*+\delta]\cap S_f = \emptyset$, so $x^*+\delta$ is a larger lower bound for $S_f$.  But $x^*$ is the greatest lower bound for $S_f$, so this is a contradiction.  We conclude that $f(x^*)\leq 0$.

On the other hand, if $y^*<0$ we let $\epsilon = -y^*/2$ and again choose $\delta$ such that for every $x\in[x^*-\delta,x^*]$, 
$$|f(x)-f(x^*)|<\epsilon.$$ 
In particular, for such $x$, $f(x) < y^*/2 < 0$.  Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, we can find a rational number $q\in [x^*-\delta, x^*]$ such that $f(q) < 0$.  This implies that $x^*$ is not a lower bound for $S_f$, and thus cannot be the infimum.  This is a contradiction, so we must have $f(x^*) \geq 0$.

We conclude that $f(x^*)=0$, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you have done and have read through this solution  but I think i need to prove it using the defintion of epsilon and infimum.. the other answer was more clear..

Comment: We have used the definition of the infimum, several times in this answer, so I'm not sure what your comment means.  Although, if the other answer is clearer to you, that's great!  I just wanted to provide a method that works when you don't know what the zero should be.